# Is it possible to perform an assignment in a PHP return statement?

Tags: php

I have a quick question regarding PHP's return statement. In C++, we're able to perform the following:

```
... function body ...
return (foo = bar, biz());
```

Where the variable `bar` is assigned to `foo` before the result of `biz()` is returned.

Is this possible (or something similar) in PHP? The above statement in PHP results in a parse error. Now, I'm aware that I can simply perform the assignment before the return statement, but this is just a contrived example, and I'm curious as to the feasibility.

**Edit**: Providing a little more clarification. Here is what I'm basically attempting to do in PHP:

```
return ($foo = $bar, biz())
    || ($foo = $bar, baz())
    || ($foo = $bar, qux());
```

`foo` is a global reference in which `biz` modifies. If `biz` returns false, the next segment in the OR statement is tested. Because `biz` returned false, I need to "reset" the value of `foo` before executing `baz` and so on and so forth.

**I'm aware that what I'm trying to do here is impure, but I'm just curious is an equivalent (or at least similar thing) is possible in PHP.**

Comment: You mean something like `return $bar = rand(1, 9);` ?

Comment: Why would assignment of local values in one function have any effect on a different function's result? Unless you are using some form of global state, which would be stupid ..

Comment: @tereško - Yes, in this example, foo is referenced in a global state. I'm aware that this normally constitutes an antipattern, but assuming that something is stupid without having full knowledge may be a bit shortsighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately PHP doesn't actually have a comma operator except in [expr1](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) of a for loop. Everywhere else a comma is just used to separate arguments to a function or language construct.

You could sort make your own comma operator user function, which just returns the last argument passed into it. Here's my shot at it:

```
function comma(){ return func_get_arg(func_num_args() - 1); }
```

With this you could use:

```
return comma($foo = $bar, biz());
```

The following complete code outputs `Hello`:

```
<?php

function foo(){
  $bar = 'Hello';
  return comma($foo = $bar, bar($foo));
}

function bar($foo){
    echo $foo;
}

foo();

function comma(){ return func_get_arg(func_num_args() - 1); }
```

**Edit**
Your sample code, using the comma function, would look like this:

```
return comma($foo = $bar, biz())
    || comma($foo = $bar, baz())
    || comma($foo = $bar, qux());
```

I honestly can't recommend using this though. That is why my short answer is "No".

Comment: Precisely what I was thinking. Thanks for your insight. I wanted to verify that there wasn't an equivalent language feature.

Comment: @naivedeveloper You're welcome! It was a good question and I learnt something from it too.  When you asked this I thought that there was indeed a comma operator, but after some more research I realized otherwise. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could return them in an array

```
return Array($foo = "bar", biz());
```

The array will contain:

```
Array ( [0] => bar [1] => A )
```

Comment: After your edit I understand what you mean, and I'm pretty sure that's not possible in PHP.

Comment: Apologies for not adequately explaining it originally. Thanks for your help.